# Can't upload multipart file from postman to spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I have the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public FileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String name = storageService.store(file);

    String uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("/download/")
            .path(name)
            .toUriString();

    return new FileResponse(name, uri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
}
```

When I try to upload file from postman I get the response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-09-12T12:42:46.493+00:00",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "path": "/upload-file"
}
```

Postman request:
[image]

Postman headers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the reason why this is happening is because your call in Postman is not specifying the response media type nor is your endpoint.

So your current call is saying `Accept: */*` (anything), and your endpoint isn't specific about what `FileResponse` should be returned as.

So, assuming you want a json response, you either need to update your Postman call to include

```
Accept: application/json
```

or  your endpoint

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Another way to do this is to annotate your controller class with a `@RestController` and simplify your endpoint method by removing the `@ResponseBody` and going with `@PostMapping(value = "/upload-file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)` and you should be good to go.

Example:

```
@RestController
public class UploadController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/upload-file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public FileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```