# Cannot save the data when using RedirectAttributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect

When I add "RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes" to String saveUser of PostMapping I got Error status 500.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM36L.png)

I think maybe syntax of PostMapping or FileUploadUtil file has error but can't find anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70BT.png)

Before that, if I comment the code in line 50 -> 53 and using the code in line 55 -> 60 the code will run normally.

Hope anyone can help me fix this.

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are getting the error from chrome browser, that browser is sending a GET request to the url you provide but the code you show expecting POST, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/73689572/175554 and the answer, it is showing how you can call the end point.